# How to learn spec type from helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

I'm writing specs from my little website, and I stuck with a little problem.

I have some spec helper methods, like:

```
  def is_logged_in?(spec = :feature)
    if spec == :feature
      page.has_selector?('#user-menu')
    else
      !session[:user_id].nil?
    end
  end
```

But I'm tired of passing the "spec" argument, and I think that there is better solution, like: `if current_spec.type == :feature ...`.

Is there a way to learn type of current running spec from helper method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to distinguish feature spec from other specs:

```
def feature_test?
  defined?(visit)
end
```

And it fits my code well =-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the type of a rspec test using this:

```
example.metadata[:type]
# => :controller # in case of a controller spec
```

Note that, `example` is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). `example` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

Comment: Hm-m... I need to acces in from `it` block... In example group it is kinda useless for me...

Comment: Unfortunately, rspec does not support that. You can not access that from an `it` block.

Comment: You are welcome. I think you have to figure out some other way. There is always an other way, a better way :)